# RUTA script not recognizing pattern when given without spaces

Tags: regex, uima, ruta, pega

I am trying to extract the last 3 characters from a pattern using below script.
But its not working for patterns given without spaces.

Below is code that I have tried:

```
((W|NUM)* (W|NUM)*){REGEXP(".{2}")-> MARK(VarA)}
 (WS|"-")?  
((W|NUM)* (W|NUM)*){REGEXP(".{7}")-> MARK(VarB)}
 (WS|"-")?
  W{REGEXP(".{3}")-> MARK(VarC),MARK(EntityType,1,5), UNMARK(VarA), UNMARK(VarB), UNMARK(VarC)};
```

Example 1:

> I/P : A1-1B1A21A-PAD
>
> O/P : PAD

Example 2:

> I/P : A11B1A21APAD
>
> Exp OP : PAD

The 1st example is working fine. But its not working for 2nd example. Its not recognizing when given without "space"

Please share your thoughts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will not suggest to match without space or `-`. Because it will return last 3 characters of all 12 digit words.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code as:
((W|NUM)* (W|NUM)*){REGEXP(".{12}")-> MARK(VarA),MARK(EntityType,1), UNMARK(VarA)};

But I am stuck on how to extract the last 3 characters of matched string.

Input : AB1234567CAB
Output: CAB

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the last 3 characters of any string in UIMA Ruta, then the following rule should do the job:

```
"(...)$" -> 1 = VarC;
```

You could then filter out the matched false positives.